# how does the producer communicate with the registry and what does it send to the registry

Tags: apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to understand this by reading the documentation but maybe because I'm not an advanced programmer I do not really understand it.

I'm in the documentation and for example in this example:
https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/serdes-protobuf.html#protobuf-serializer

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
  "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
  "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufSerializer");
props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://127.0.0.1:8081");

Producer<String, MyRecord> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, MyRecord>(props);

String topic = "testproto";
String key = "testkey";
OtherRecord otherRecord = OtherRecord.newBuilder()
  .setOtherId(123).build();
MyRecord myrecord = MyRecord.newBuilder()
  .setF1("value1").setF2(otherRecord).build();

ProducerRecord<String, MyRecord> record
      = new ProducerRecord<String, MyRecord>(topic, key, myrecord);
producer.send(record).get();
producer.close();
```

I see here that you define the schema registry url and then somehow the producer will know that it will send contact to the registry to provide some metadata on the messages to the registry.

Now I would like to understand better how does this actually work and what is exchanged between the producer and the registry (or is kafka that contact with the registry)?

Anyway my question is imagine I have a record that is in a protobuf format.
I'm putting that protobuf into kafka in a certain topic.
now I want to activate the schema registry so would the producer just send the proto definition into the schema registry?
does the producer just get the metadata definition directly from the record?
would it try to update in any new message into the queue? would this not increase a bit the latency when pushing the data to kafka?

Sorry if this is all very basic questions but I'm just trying to get the bigger picture and I'm missing this peace.

Thanks for any information, sorry if this is already clear from the documentation.
(I need to have this so that I can use ksql to deserialize my messages in kafka)

best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would the producer just send the proto definition into the schema registry

The Serializer does, not the Producer directly.

`MyRecord` is serialized to binary, the schema is sent over HTTP to the Registry, which returns an ID, then the sent message contains `0x0 + ID + binary-protobuf-value`

[Source code here](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/protobuf-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/protobuf/AbstractKafkaProtobufSerializer.java#L77-L100)

> would it try to update in any new message into the queue?

Schema gets sent before any messages are sent. Existing messages are untouched

> would this not increase a bit the latency when pushing the data to kafka?

Only for the first message since the schema gets cached